# In Excel, how do I put text in a specific cell based on a value?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have 7 different cells (corresponding to days of the week) and a volatile value (the current day of the week) using which I want to put a text value in its appropriate cell.

For example, if the day of the week is 1, then the text should be put in cell A1; if the day of the week is 2, then the text should be put in cell A2, and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need more detail here, on what you are trying to do.  What have you tried?  Why don't you just type in the dates?

Comment: @JamesJenkins: The idea is that the text is automatically put in a cell based on which day of the week the spreadsheet is opened on.

Comment: Never mind, I asked the same question at Yahoo! Answers and got a solution. For anybody interested, here's the link: [http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130309065013AAsaoA9](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130309065013AAsaoA9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a worksheet function, you can put the following in seven adjacent columns :

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(NOW()) = COLUMN() - 0 ; "Text" ; "")
```

Replace the 0 with the number of the first column-1 (0 is the correct value for column A).

As a line in a VBA subroutine :

```
[A1:G1].Cells(1, DatePart("w", Date)).Value = "Text"
```

The range is specified in the square brackets.

In both cases, 1 = Sunday ; see the help for DatePart or Weekday to use a different starting day.